# Particles: Smooth random lifetime

Tags: particles

I have a particle system with 1 million particles.
The particles all spawn on frame 1, have a lifetime of 80 frames and random lifetime set to 1.

The particles despawn nicely over time until frame 79. There are still too many particles alive so about 200000 particles (not an exact number) despawn between frame 79 and 80.

Is there a way to apply a curve to the random lifetime value (or a similar approach) to achieve a nicer desintegration of the system?

Comment: In the current particle-system of the blender, there is no way to apply a curve to particles lifetime. However, you can use texture (gradient texture) to affect the lifetime of particles.